# Sequentially validating individual attributes with Django Rest Framework

Tags: python, django, rest, django-rest-framework

I am very new to Django Rest Framework and am confused about coding the following task: when a user on the front-end enters an email address, without any other user information, the API should determine whether or not the email already exists. Likewise, when the user enters a username, without any other user information, the API should determine whether or not the username already exists. This is so the user has feedback on whether their email or username is valid before proceeding to the next sign up stage.

I am aware of the existence of validators, but I don't understand how to use them on partial data.

Here is my serializers.py class

```
class CustomUserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    email = serializers.EmailField(required=True)
    username = serializers.CharField(min_length=2)
    password = serializers.CharField(min_length=8, write_only=True)
    first_name = serializers.CharField(min_length=2)
    last_name = serializers.CharField(min_length=2)



    class Meta:
        model = CustomUser
        fields = ('pk', 'email', 'username', 'password', 'created_at', 'first_name', 'last_name')
        extra_kwargs = {'password': {'write_only': True}}

    def validate_email(self, value):
        if CustomUser.objects.filter(email=value).exists():
            raise serializers.ValidationError("An account already exists with that email address.")
        return value

    def validate_username(self, value):
        if CustomUser.objects.filter(username=value).exists():
            raise serializers.ValidationError("An account aready exists with that username.")
        return value

    def create(self, validated_data):
        password = validated_data.pop('password', None)
        instance = self.Meta.model(**validated_data)
        if password is not None:
            instance.set_password(password)
        instance.save()
        return instance
```

And here is my views.py class

```
class CustomUserCreate(APIView):
    permission_classes = (permissions.AllowAny,)
    authentication_classes = ()

    def post(self, request, format='json'):
        """
        Receives an HTTP request. Serializes and saves a user object.

        """

        serializer = CustomUserSerializer(data=request.data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            user = serializer.save()
            if user:
                json = serializer.data
                return Response(json, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
            return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)

class CustomUserGet(APIView):

    def get_user(self, username):
        try:
            return CustomUser.objects.get(username=username)
        except CustomUser.DoesNotExist:
            raise Http404

    def get(self, request, format='json'):
        user = self.get_user(request.user.username)
        serializer = CustomUserSerializer(user)
        return Response(serializer.data)


class LogoutAndBlacklistRefreshTokenForUserView(APIView):
    permission_classes = (permissions.AllowAny,)

    def post(self, request):
        try:
            refresh_token = request.data['refresh_token']
            token = RefreshToken(refresh_token)
            token.blacklist()
            return Response(status=status.HTTP_205_RESET_CONTENT)
        except:
            return Response(status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

`CustomUser` is simply an implementation of `AbstractUser`.

Again, this successfully validates when a user is created with complete data. However, I want to validate on ***partial*** data, such as a lone email address and lone username without the presence of other attributes such as first_name, last_name, etc. What is the proper way of approaching this?

Comment: If you want a separate endpoint for validating the email and username why not create it? Then you can use a serializer that only takes the fields you want to validate